# Display Multiple Year's Data Using Custom Start/End Dates - datetime, matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I feel like this question has an obvious answer and I'm just being a bit of a fool. Say you have a couple of dataframes with datetime indices, where each dataframe is for a different year. In my case the index is every day going from June 25th to June 24th the next year:

```
date        var
2019-06-25  107.230294
2019-06-26  104.110004
2019-06-27  104.291506
2019-06-28  111.162552
2019-06-29  112.515364
...
2020-06-20  132.840242
2020-06-21  127.641148
2020-06-22  132.797584
2020-06-23  129.094451
2020-06-24  110.408866
```

What I want is a single plot with multiple lines, where each line represents a year. The y-axis is my variable, `var`, and the x-axis should be day of the year. The x-axis should start from June 25th and end at June 24th.

This is what I've tried so far but it messes up the x-axis. Anyone know a more elegant way to do this?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(average_prices19.index.strftime("%d/%m"), average_prices19.var, label = "2019-20")
plt.plot(average_prices20.index.strftime("%d/%m"), average_prices20.var, label = "2020-21")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a twist in this question: the list of dates in a year is not constant: on leap years there is a `'Feb-29'` that is otherwise absent.

If you are comfortable glossing over this (and always representing a potential `'Feb-29'` date on your plot, with missing data for non-leap years), then the following will achieve what you are seeking (assuming the data is in `df` with the date as `DateTimeIndex`):

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for label, dfy in df.assign(
    # note: 2000 is a leap year; the choice is deliberate
    date=pd.to_datetime(df.index.strftime('2000-%m-%d')),
    label=df.index.strftime('%Y')
).groupby('label'):
    dfy.set_index('date')['var'].plot(ax=ax, label=str(label))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%m-%d"))
ax.legend()
```

**Update**

For larger amounts of data however, the above does not produce very legible xlabels. So instead, we can use [`ConciseFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.ConciseDateFormatter) to customize the display of xlabels (and remove the *fake* year 2000):

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for label, dfy in df.assign(
    # note: 2000 is a leap year; the choice is deliberate
    date=pd.to_datetime(df.index.strftime('2000-%m-%d')),
    label=df.index.strftime('%Y')
).groupby('label'):
    dfy.set_index('date')['var'].plot(ax=ax, label=str(label))
ax.legend()

locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=3, maxticks=7)
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(
    locator,
    formats=['', '%b', '%d', '%H:%M', '%H:%M', '%S.%f'],
    offset_formats=['', '', '%b', '%b-%d', '%b-%d', '%b-%d %H:%M']
)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

For the data in your example:

[image]

For more data:

```py
# setup
idx = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', 'now', freq='QS')
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'var': np.random.uniform(size=len(idx))},
    index=idx).resample('D').interpolate(method='polynomial', order=5)
```

Corresponding plot (with `ConciseFormatter`):

[image]